# Do we really need generic class with type constraint?

Tags: c#, generics

Sorry if title of question is a little bit vague.

Suppose we have the following code

```
class ReportManager<T> where T : IPrint
{
    public void MakePaperCopy(T t)
    {
        //...
        t.Print();
        //...
    }
}

public interface IPrint
{
    void Print();
}
```

It can be easily remade to non-generic version. Like this

```
class ReportManager
{
    public void MakePaperCopy(IPrint print)
    {
        //...
        print.Print();
        //...
    }
}
```

**Are there some advantages in first case ?** it seems no. 

**Can i say that every generic class with single `where T: ISomeInterface` can be easily remade to non-generic version and it should be done because it reduces the complexity of code ?**

Comment: In this simple example it does make sense to simplify it, but think about the case when `ReportManager` is to be inherited and `MakePaperCopy` is `virtual`.

Comment: It also makes sense to use a generic constraint when you want to expose an instance of the generic parameter out of the class - like `Task<T>` - you need to get access to the strongly-typed value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first place, generics avoid a lot of casts. This can ends up in significant performance gains in intensive applications and services.

Secondly, it's not the same defining that a generic type parameter accepts any implementation of `IPrint` (non-generic) than that the whole type will handle objects which are forced to implement `IPrint` (generic).

Try to work on the following type requirement without generics:

- I want that `T` to be `IPrint` and inherit `PrintablePaper`.

Without generics, sadly, this would be implemented using reflection:

```
// Ugly as hell. And error prone, because it's verified during
// run-time...
if(typeof(IPrint).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)) && typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(PrintablePaper)) 
{
}
```

With generics: `T : PrintablePaper, IPrint` and try to give a wrong type as generic argument, and compiler will say: *slap in your face, slap in your face, ...*.

Basically, in terms of high-level programming, generics were introduced to enforce *strongly-typing* in C# *even more*. Generic constraints provide details to what would be an acceptable generic argument during compile-time. That is, generics are a good way to close a software architecture/design to grow based on specs defined by generic constraints.

About the whole repository sample, if your report manager will never need to handle specializations of `IPrint`, generics are useless in that particular case: accepting implementations of `IPrint` or a *type which mandatorily will implement `IPrint`* is almost the same in your case.

In your case, it would be useful if you would need to *inherit that class*:

```
class ReportManager<T> where T : IPrint
{
    public void MakePaperCopy(T t)
    {
        //...
        t.Print();
        //...
    }
}

class SpecializedReportManager : ReportManager<FancyReport>
{
    // Beat this without generics!!
    // In inherited classes, you can work with the IReport
    // implementation directly and without casts!
    public void MakePaperCopy(FancyReport t)
    {
        //...
        t.Print();
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed and well-formed answer !

Comment: @Disappointed No problem, you're welcome, and I hope you got in love with generics ;)

Answer (score 5):

It's not useless in all cases.
If you want to return this `T`, then you may want to know the exact type.
Because when you are returning it, you can access to all the (accessible) members from the derived class, not only those from the base class/interface.

Comment: It's not only true for return values; even if no member of your generic class ever returns T (in any form), you still may want to guarantee that a developer will be able to limit the input parameters to a specific type.

Comment: Maybe, but not the most visual example. If you make a specific constraint not only on the base class/interface, then, I agree. Otherwise, I don't see (at the moment) why the generic would be required.

Comment: Quick and silly example - imagine for a moment you want a `Hashset<T>` where you never want to access previously entered items - basically you're using it only for checking if an item appeared previously. If you have `Hashset<int>`, the developer will never by accident add a `String`, otherwise that would be possible (for the sake of argument imagine that in our custom hashset we're enforcing `where T : IComparable<T>`).

Comment: Ok. Then it's more likely to be required for value types, than reference ones. Am I right ?

Comment: No, why? Change `int` to `System.Windows.Control` in my example and the logic (assuming it's valid :P) will be the same.

Comment: @romain-aga: The post does state a _single_ `where ...` constraint. So the combination with `new()` is a different case.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: You are right. You think I should remove it ?

Comment: Remove that part, maybe. Or think about another counter example.

Answer (score 2):

The generic form will prevent boxing in case of value types.

Also, you can have T implement multiple interfaces:

```
class ReportManager<T> where T : IPrint, IConvertible, IAnotherInterface
```

The 2nd form will obviously not work in that case.

Comment: yes, if there are a few type constrains it's really impossible to remake to non-generic version. So  it will be easier in future to improve\add new functionality with generic version ...

Answer (score 0):

After commenting on [romain-aga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5813357/romain-aga)'s post - there's yet another reason, on top of what everyone else said. If you have a constraint referencing a generic interface (say `where T : IComparable<T>`) you simply won't be able to remake it into a non-generic version.

Comment: What exactly is 'simplify' here?

Comment: Was fairly certain OP used that term, fixed; thanks!